# Using GitHub as a Version Control Tool for a hosted Drupal Site

Tags: git, drupal

Would like to know how to use GitHub as a version control system for my hosted Drupal site. What are steps that I need to take to push files from Drupal to GitHub? What files/directories are best to push over to GitHub.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you aren't already familiar with **git** you will need to read this ...

- http://www.opensourcery.com/blog/alex-kroman/getting-started-git

Hosting on Github and then cloning to your hosting deployment directory, you'd simply do..

```
git clone git://github.com/your-github-account/your-github-repo.git
```

To initially deploy.

And then: (when there are changes to deploy)

```
git pull
```

To update the site to the latest version of your site.

(both commands executed on the shell of the server, and assuming git is available there)

### Github's SVN support

If you don't have git available on the hosting server (and it cannot be installed for some reason), Github also allows you to checkout a repository over Subversion.

```
svn co http://svn.github.com/your-github-account/your-github-repo.git .
```

To do the initial deploy... and:

```
svn up
```

To deploy new changes.